# Filter inner list using stream in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to apply a second filter for my product category list as shown below:

```
final List<ProductCategoryDTO> productCategoryList = productCategoryService
        .findAllByUuid(uuid)
        .stream()
        .filter(category -> !category.getProductList().isEmpty())
        // I am trying to filter the productCategoryList based on 
        // the "isDisabled" value of inner list >>>
        .filter(category -> category.getProductList().stream()
            .anyMatch(p -> !p.getMenuProperties().isDisabled()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first filter `!category.getProductList().isEmpty()` is applied to the productCategoryList (outer list) and then I also want to apply a filter based on inner list's `isDisabled` value. I tried to use `flatMap` and concatenate the filter conditions as shown below, but none of them is not working:

```
.filter(category -> !category.getProductList().isEmpty() && 
    !category.getProductList().stream()
        .anyMatch(p -> p.getMenuProperties().isDisabled()))
```

So, how can I filter `productCategoryList` based on inner list value?

Here are the related DTO's:

```java
public class ProductCategoryDTO {
    private UUID uuid;
    private List<MenuCategoryDTO> productList;
}
```

```java
public class MenuCategoryDTO {
    private MenuPropertiesDTO menuProperties;
}
```

**Update:** I also need to retrieve the list of UUID values of products by flattening the lists as shown below. But it does not work:

```
final List<UUID> productUuidList = productCategoryList.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getProductList().stream())
        .flatMap(b -> b.getMenuProperties().getUuid())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your code in the first filter is different from the second code. `anyMatch( ! condition)` IS NOT same as    
`! anyMatch(condition)`. First one returns true if at least one is not disabled, whereas the second return true only when none are disabled

Comment: Then I misused `anyMatch`, but I already ask the true usage example. So, any suggestion please?

Comment: Your second code snippet should work. But I suggest `noneMatch` instead of `!anymatch` -> `filter(category -> !category.getProductList().isEmpty() &&  category.getProductList().stream() .noneMatch(p -> p.getMenuProperties().isDisabled()))`

Comment: Thanks, but it returns 0 record even if there are mixed records with `getMenuProperties().isDisabled()` is true and false. I am not sure if `match` methods are used for boolean result. Any idea by using different approaches e.g. `flatMap` ?

Comment: Yes, AllMatch, AnyMatch and NoneMatch are not suitable for my situation, because I need a list instead of boolean result. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, are you saying that you do not need to filter out the `ProductCategoryDTO` item, but instead want a sublist of products which are not disabled?

Comment: No, I want to apply filter on `category.getProductList()` based on the value of `category.getProductList().getMenuProperties().isDisabled()` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `category.getProductList()` is not an immutable list, then you could use

```java
List<ProductCategoryDTO> list = productCategoryService.findAllByUuid(uuid);
list.stream()
    .filter(category -> !category.getProductList().isEmpty())        
    .forEach(category -> category.getProductList()
                                 .removeIf(p -> p.getMenuProperties().isDisabled()));
```

Comment: On the other hand, how can I get the `UUID` of the `list` by flattening products in each categories? Assume that there are 2 categories and in each category, there are 3 products. So, I need to retrieve 6 `UUID` of these products. How can I do that? I tried but failed :(

Comment: I added an update regarding to building uuid list. Any idea?

Comment: @Ashley The second one should be `map` instead of `flatMap`

Answer (score 0):

You get Stream of MenuCategoryDTO object after 1st flatMap. So you don't need 2nd flatMap. You can use Map instead.

```
final List<UUID> productUuidList = productCategoryList.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> a.getProductList().stream())
    .map(b -> b.getMenuProperties().getUuid())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```